# Why do i need to press each time twice on the mouse middle button to change the flag bool between true/false instead with one click each time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The problem is that the flag bool `autoRotate` changes only after the second press/click on the mouse middle button and not on the first press/click.

```
public class ConeRotation : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float rotSpeed = 250;
    public float damping = 10;

    private float desiredRot;
    private bool autoRotate = false;

    void Start()
    {
        desiredRot = transform.eulerAngles.z;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            if (Input.mousePosition.x > Screen.width / 2) desiredRot -= rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            else desiredRot += rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
        {
            if (Input.mousePosition.x > Screen.width / 2) desiredRot -= rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            else desiredRot -= rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(2))
        {
            autoRotate = !autoRotate;
        }

        if (autoRotate)
        {
            desiredRot += rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        var desiredRotQ = Quaternion.Euler(transform.eulerAngles.x, transform.eulerAngles.y, desiredRot);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, desiredRotQ, Time.deltaTime * damping);
    }
}
```

In this part I need to press the middle button of the mouse twice to change the flag either from false to true and then from true to false and I want to do it in one press/click on the middle button.

```
if (Input.GetMouseButton(2))
{
    autoRotate = !autoRotate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's three ways to read buttons with the original Input system. "Button Down", "Button" and "Button Up".

When dealing with the mouse buttons, if you want to read a middle mouse button pressed, you could simply look for each `GetMouseButtonDown(2)`, as such:

```cs
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(2))
{
    autoRotate = !autoRotate;
}
```

In your current code, you're reading the mouse button status every frame. The code sees that the mouse button is still pressed (`GetMouseButton(2)` tells you if the button is still pressed), and then flips the value of `autoRotate`. What you observe as you needing to press the button twice was likely just happenstance, and the value of `autoRotate` had been rapidly changing every single frame, and it just looked like it required two (or more) presses to get the value you were expecting.

On another note, are you positive the rest of the code is correct? It looks like some of the +ive and -ive signs aren't quite right. Maybe you meant?

```cs
if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
{
    if (Input.mousePosition.x > Screen.width / 2)
        desiredRot += rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    else
        desiredRot -= rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

}
```